# why library_FOUND is not set?

Tags: cmake

I am using an external CMake library.
I use `find_package(libary)` in my CMakeLists.txt.

```
message("phasar_INCLUDE_DIR: ${PHASAR_INCLUDE_DIR}")

find_package(phasar COMPONENTS llvm_ifdside REQUIRED)
if(PHASAR_FOUND)
    message("phasar found")
endif()
message("phasar_INCLUDE_DIR: ${PHASAR_INCLUDE_DIR}")
```

I can see that the last message command outputs the directory of the external library.

Why does `PHASAR_FOUND` not set?

Comment: The output variable is prefixed with the same name as you passed to `find_package`. That is, in your case the variable is named as `phasar_FOUND`.